# Replacing digits with dashes in the given string

Tags: java, string

I am trying to understand why does this code doesn´t work.

Write a code to replace the digits with dashes in the given string. Letters remain unchanged.

My code:

import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaApp {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner vstup = new Scanner(System.in);
  String a = vstup.nextLine();
  String b = "";
  
  for (int index=0;index<10;index++) {
  b= (a.replace('0','-'));   
    b= (a.replace('1','-'));
     b= (a.replace('2','-'));   
    b= (a.replace('3','-'));
     b= (a.replace('4','-'));   
    b= (a.replace('5','-'));      
     b= (a.replace('6','-'));   
    b= (a.replace('7','-'));
     b= (a.replace('8','-'));   
    b= (a.replace('9','-'));
    
    
  }


  System.out.println(b);
  
  
} }
```

Feedback appreciated :)

Comment: replace the `''` with this `""`

Comment: What do you think should happen in each step? What is the purpose of loop if you manually point out all digits? Are you aware that string are immutable? Why you are always "modifying" `a` but assigning result to `b`?

Comment: Because the input a is given.

Answer (score 2):

First of, you don't modify `a`. It will always contain your input. Every time you call `replace` a new String is created and returned with the modified value. `a` remains the same, still containing the old values. Assigning `b` multiple times in a row means that `b` will at the end contain only the last String created from the last called `replace`. In your case `b = a with dash instead of 9` because last thing you replace is '9'. Digits from 0-8 will still be contained in `b` since they are never removed from `a`.

Second, your way of doing this is correct but you picked the hard route. Strings support the usage of regex. If you don't know them, take a look at them. They allow to define logical sets of characters that can be matched to an input. So in other words, you can define a regex that matches any number and replace all findings inside the input. Like this

```
String numberRegex = "\\d";
String replaceValue = "-";
String result = input.replaceAll(numberRegex, replaceValue); // replaces all findings that match the regex with the replaceValue
```

To make your non-regex version to work, you would have to call replace on the string that already has the other values removed. Like this

```
String result = input;
result = result.replace('0', '-');
result = result.replace('1', '-');
// .....
```

Or you just chain them up to make it more readable. You can directly call the replace on the value that was returned by the previous replace.

```
String result = input.replace('0', '-').replace('1', '-').replace....);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
b= (a.replaceAll("\\d","-"));
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works, can you please explain to me what \\d means ?

Comment: 'd' means a digit. It replaces all digits with "-".

Comment: @HarunÖzdemir look at my answer. I explained your mistake and gave a detailed solution

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.